# parameters are not passing to the controller Rails3 + coffeescript + ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, controller, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement a sorting list with Rails3 and coffeescript. I had a routing issue earlier and was able to solve it with [your generous help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603330/ajax-update-with-coffeescript-rails3/13603389#13603389), so now I have a different issue, My data parameter is not passing to the server,

Following is my view

```
#index.html.erb 
<h1>Listing books</h1>
<ul id="books"> <% @books.each do |book| %>
  <li class="book<%= book.id %>"><span class="handle">[drag]</span><%= book.name %></li>
<% end %></ul>
<%= link_to 'New book', new_book_path %>
```

following is my books.js.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#books').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    handle: '.handle'
    update: ->
      $.post('/books/sort', $(this).data('#books'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Following is my controller

```
#books_controller.rb
def sort
  @books = Book.all
  @books.each do |book|
    book.position = params['book'].index(book.id.to_s) + 1
    book.save
  end

  render :nothing => true
end
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started POST "/books/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-28 17:03:25 +0530
Processing by BooksController#sort as */*
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `index' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:14:in `block in sort'
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:13:in `each'
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:13:in `sort'


  Rendered /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (40.8ms)
  Rendered /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (47.7ms)
```

So when i say `p params`, I get `{"action"=>"sort", "controller"=>"books"}`, So it doesnt have a param called 'book' and hence gives a nil error, can someone help me out,

any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: I would take a look at the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) docs. You can't pass multiple values to `$.post` as you're doing in your CoffeeScript and expect them to make it to the server.

Comment: What do you expect `$(this).data('#books')` to be? I don't see anything that sets that data attribute and `#books` looks more like an ID selector than a data attribute name.

Comment: Hi @JonathanTran, thanks for the answer, I changed the code to $.post('/books/sort', {book: 'sample data'}, $(this).sortable('serialize')) and was manage to pass the string sample data to the controller, but how could I pass the entire <ul> to controller for sorting !!! thanks

Comment: Hi @muistooshort, could u please tell me how to set the data attribute, what I'm trying to do here is to get the <ul> data via the command $(this).data('#books'), what would be the correct way of doing that, thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: What is supposed to be in `$(this).data('#books')`? I don't understand why you'd need it all when `$(this).sortable('serialize')` should have everything you need.

Comment: Hi @muistooshort, thanks for the answer, I did this and still the 'book' params in blank $.post('/books/sort', {book: $(this).sortable('serialize')}), any idea, thanks?

Comment: Have you looked at the `$(this).sortable('serialize')` output? Have you check the [`serialize`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) docs to make sure everything is set up properly?

Comment: Hi @muistooshort, its working now thanks a lot, as the API says I had to add an _ in <li> id attribute Ex: <li id=<added underscore here>>, if you could put this as an answer I could accept it ;), anyway thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple things going wrong here. First of all, your [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) arguments are a bit confused:

```
$.post('/books/sort', $(this).data('#books'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

`$.post` wants the data in the second argument so just this:

```
$.post('/books/sort', $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

makes more sense.

Sortable's [`serialize` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) wants DOM `id` attributes to be in a specific form:

> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format `"setname_number"`, and it spits out a hash like `"setname[]=number&setname[]=number"`.

In your Rails controller, you want an array of book IDs in `params[:book]` so you want `book[]=id&book[]=id&...` going to your server. That means that you want your `<li>`s to look more like this:

```
<li id="book_<%= book.id %>">
```

Or you could keep use `class` attributes by including an underscore:

```
<li class="book_<%= book.id %>">
```

and then telling `serialize` to look at `class`:

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', attribute: 'class')
```

You should also use the `expression` option and leave the HTML alone:

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', attribute: class, expression: /(book)(.+)/)
```

There are a few other ways to arrange things, see the [sortable documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) for further details.